# Update Data with Bootstrap Modal using CodeIgniter and Ajax

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure it out why I can't get the alert warning or success from the form validation in a modal. all I want at first is to update the data in the database and it work. now I can't see the alert whether it is wrong or correct, the modal close after I submit and how can I transfer the echo json_encode to alert in modal

view: layout view

```js
 $('#login_form').on('submit', function( event ){
  event.preventDefault();
  var Admin_id = $('#Admin_id').val();
  var username = $('#username').val();
  var email    = $('#email').val();
  var contact  = $('#contact').val();
  var hoax     = $('#hoax').val();
  var confirm  = $('#confirm').val();
  var date     = $('#date').val();

  $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url('profile/profile_update'); ?>",
      method: "POST",
      data: {Admin_id:Admin_id, username:username, email:email, 
      contact:contact, confirm:confirm, date:date, hoax:hoax},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
          if (data.result){
         $('#result').html('<p class="alert-success"> The inputs are insufficient </p>');
       }else{
         $('#result').html('<p class="alert-warning"> The profile successfully updated</p>');
       }
          //return false;
          //event.preventDefault();
      }
  });
  return false;
  //event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="profile" id="1" href="#Profile_modal" data-toggle="modal">Profile</a>

<div class="modal" id="Profile_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable" >
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-secondary">
        <h5 class="modal-title text-white">Profile</h5>
        <button type="button " class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span class="text-white" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" >
        <div class="text-center" id="result"> </div>
        <div id="data_profile"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller: profile/profile_update

```
public function profile_update(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|min_length[13]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact', 'Contact', 'trim|required|min_length[11]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('hoax', 'Password', 
    'trim|required|min_length[6]|matches[confirm]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm', 'ConfirmPassword', 'trim|required|min_length[6]');
    
    
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $data = array('profile_errors' => validation_errors());
        echo json_encode(array("result"=>false));
        
     }else{
        
        $this->load->model('admin_model');
        $data=$this->profile_model->update_data();
        //$data = 'Your Profile Data has been Updated Successfully';
        echo json_encode(array("result"=>true));
        
     }  
}
```

profile/get_fetchdata()

```
public function get_fetchdata(){
    $Admin_id = $this->input->post('Admin_id');
    if(isset($Admin_id) and !empty($Admin_id)){
        $records = $this->profile_model->fetch_data($Admin_id);
        $output = '';

        foreach ($records->result_array() as $row) {                
            $attributes = array('id'=>'login_form', 'class'=>'form');

            $output = '<div class="text-center" id="result"> </div>';

            echo form_open('profile/profile_update', $attributes);

            $output = '
              <div class="form-group text-left">
                <label> Username </label>
                <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" value='. $row["username"] .' placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" maxlength="10" required>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group text-left">
                <label> Email </label>
                <input type="Email" id="email" class="form-control" value='. $row["email"] .' placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" maxlength="20" required>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group text-left">
                <label> Phone Number</label>
                <input type="number" id="contact" class="form-control" value='.$row["contact"].' placeholder="Enter Phone Number" name="contact" maxlength="11" required>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group text-left">
                <label> Password </label>
                <input type="password" id="hoax" class="form-control" value='. $row["hoax"].' placeholder="Enter Password" name="hoax" maxlength="15" required>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group text-left">
                <label> Confirm Password </label>
                <input type="password" id="confirm" class="form-control" value='.$row["hoax"].' placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirm" maxlength="15" required>
              </div>
              
              <input type="hidden" id="Admin_id" class="form-control" value='. $row["Admin_id"] .' name="Admin_id">
              <input type="hidden" id="date" class="form-control" value='. $row["date_modified"] .' name="date">

              <button class="btn btn-primary float-right new_profile" id="1" name="submit" type="submit" >Save</button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger mx-2 float-right" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"> Cancel </button>';
            echo form_close();
        }
        echo $output;
    }else {
        echo "Nothing to show";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use json as dataType, the browser will wait always for a JSON response, so the best thing to do here is the following:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    echo json_encode(array("result" => false, "message" => "Failed"));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array("result" => true, "message" => "Success!"));
}
```

and you can check the results on ajax side by using:

```
$('#login_form').on('submit', function( event ){
  event.preventDefault();
  var Admin_id = $('#Admin_id').val();
  var username = $('#username').val();
  var email    = $('#email').val();
  var contact  = $('#contact').val();
  var hoax     = $('#hoax').val();
  var confirm  = $('#confirm').val();
  var date     = $('#date').val();

  $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url('profile/profile_update'); ?>",
      method: "POST",
      data: {Admin_id:Admin_id, username:username, email:email, 
      contact:contact, confirm:confirm, date:date, hoax:hoax},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
          if(data.result){
                  $('#adminId').val("");
                  $('#username').val("");
                  $('#email').val("");
                  $('#contact').val("");
                  $('#hoax').val("");
                  $('#confirm').val("");
                  $('#date').val("");
              $('#result').html('<p class="alert-success"> ' + data.message + ' </p>');
          }else{
              $('#result').html('<p class="alert-warning"> ' + data.message + ' </p>'); 
          }
          //return false;
          //event.preventDefault();
      }
  });
  return false;
  //event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: hi I appreciate your answer even I tried your suggestion but no alert it didn't submit

Comment: i tried to remove the 2 $output and change it to echo and it work but  the page was redirected to plain white

Comment: you need to change the success function inside your json to match the response, as well you need to some extra text for the array to echo it in your html, i've updated the code to match your request

Comment: Yes, if the array('profile_errors' => validation_errors()); based on each input names, then instead of just adding html warning or errors, you can add error statement to each input on failed response by using the input name, like this:
$("input[name='username']).addClass("has-error");

Comment: yes it worked ...but the problem is ..it stays after I make changes and when i click  it did not submit. i know it work because I change the $output to echo and redirected me to a plain page and thiers i found the json array

Comment: Open the network panel in Chrome and debug the click function, see the console for any javascript errors! good luck